# Maven exclude philosophy

Tags: maven, architecture, dependency-management

- What maven [*Excluded dependencies*](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) was invented for?
- Should I care to exclude any dependencies other then for fixing libraries conflicts?
- What would good maven project architecture look like:

  - tend to exclude as much as possible
  - or as minimum as needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the reasons for the design but I've seen it used in the following cases:

- I had a library which had `junit` as a compile time dependency so JUnit code leaked into my production code.
- I had a library which uses `log4j`. Since I'm using `slf4j`, I used dependency exclusion to get rid of the hardwired logging framework and used a `slf4j-log4j` bridge instead so I could ultimately log to `logback`.
- In another case, I was using only some features of a framework and didn't need all the dependencies. Since they weren't optional in the first place, I used exclusions to keep my classpath lean and clean.

General rules:

1. Use it to get rid of things that break your build
2. Get rid of things that you're replacing with something else
3. Get rid of things that you know you don't need (optional)

If none of the rules apply, leave the dependency alone; chances are that the immediate dependency might change over time and suddenly, it will need some dependency that seemed superfluous before and you code will unexpectedly break.

Comment: As far as I understood you propose to scrutinize all dependency tree and clean as much as possible for each dependency?

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych: Please don't do this. Only exclude real problems.

Comment: thus, I would not bother about step 3 from your answer and keep my pom clean leaving classpath 'as is', right?

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych: The 3rd rule is purely optional. I've updated my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: your first 2 cases and blackbuild's answer is clear examples of problems maven did provide exclude to solve. Third case is something I want to discuss here. If I use only part of functionality from some library should I care to exclude everything else (and introduce some mess in build config, make support some more complicated etc.)? Maven exclude can do this, but was it intended for this? What is good style here?

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych Can you be sure that the dependency you exclude is not needed? What about a new version of the library? The correct way would have been for the library provider to set optional libraries really optional, because it uses features that the library can work without. Exmpl: dom4j CAN work with jaxen, but it can also work without, if you do not need XPath support. Therefore, jaxen is an optional dependency to dom4j. If the dom4j providers forgot to add "optional", you could exclude jaxen. But you need to know exactly what you are doing. Exclude should be an exception, not a rule.

Comment: so you tent to agree that I should not care to exclude any dependencies other then for fixing libraries conflicts and usually I should exclude as minimum as needed (conflicts, overrides). This is the very question from the start... (I can see a project where exclude is 'common approach' and before I add any dependency I'm advised to review dependency tree and exclude any non-needed artifacts. I think this is misuse of exclude, wanted to start a topic on stack overflow. (this is not small project to care about bits of space)

Comment: I'd like to ask why this rule was put into place. Maybe someone likes to spend time on premature optimization or maybe it's a legal requirement or FUD ("maybe some unnecessary dependency could cause trouble"). One of the main reasons to use Maven is that it automatically locates all dependencies, so it's much easier to split projects into small pieces without forcing consumers to spend hours or days to figure out what they need to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Aaron's answer:

An exclusion is usually needed when the provider of the dependency did something wrong (i.e. did not make a dependency optional where he should have, included an actual logging backend - as opposed to api - or used the wrong scope).

The one exception is logging frameworks. See Aaron's answer for that.

So no, do only exclude dependencies if you have a specific reason to exclude them.